# Previously used by a large number of people

Tags: visual, rebus

I got this puzzle from a friend of mine. I can't seem to figure out what the message is suppose to be. He only said: *"although the rebus is not fully complete and rearrangement is necessary, it should be enough to solve this puzzle"*

So far I haven't solved it. Can you help me out?

---

I ----- --I- --I-- --M-- --M---L- --L-.

**9.81**
-**2.72** 
✍️ 
 
 
️ 
 
1️⃣

---

**What's the hidden message?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is:

> **I wrote this using Roman numerals only.**

The rearanged parts of the rebus are:

> **I**       — an eye
>  **WROTE**   — a writing hand
>  **THIS**    — a pointing hand
>  **US**      — United States
>  **IN**      — India
>  **G**       — 9.81 (m/s², Earth's gravity)
>  · · ·
>  **ONE**     — number one
>  minus **E** — −2.72 (an approximation of −e)
>  **LY**      — Libya
>
>  That accounts for most of the message, but there's a gap in the middle

The gap in the middle ...

> ... can be filled by observing which letters were chosen as hints in the pattern for the sentence. They are **I**, **L** and **M**, which are all roman numbers. All other letters in the sentece aren't Roman numbers; they are represented by a dash. (That also means that the second word is "wrote", not "write".)
>
>  The expression **ROMAN NUMERALS** fits the given pattern **••M•• ••M•••L•**.

As fot the title:

> Roman numerals were used by a large number of people. (We even still use them today in some contexts.) And there's the big hint "number" right there.